# Stripe: Creating invoice Item without invoice, adding invoice item into new invoice

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I created multiple invoice item without an invoice id with the following code.

```
const invoiceItem = await stripe.invoiceItems.create({
    customer: customerId,
    price,
  });
```

Now I want to send an invoice that includes all the invoice item that was created.

however I can't simply create an invoice and update my invoice item with the invoice id as stripe does not allow that.

```
  // ===== DOES NOT WORK =====
  const invoice = await stripe.invoices.create({
    customer: customerId,
    collection_method: 'send_invoice',
    days_until_due: 30,
  });
  await stripe.invoiceItems.update({
    customer: customerId,
    price,
    invoice: invoice.id,
  })
```

**what I really want to achieve is actually the following in stripe account (button circle in red)**
[image: invoice now button]

**How do I code the "Invoice now" button?** Do I need to re-create all the invoice item??

Answer (score 1):

From [API version 2022-08-01](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01):

> When the parameter is omitted the default value of pending_invoice_items_behavior is now exclude.

So you want to specify [pending_invoice_items_behavior](https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create#create_invoice-pending_invoice_items_behavior) to `include` to include all the pending Invoice Items into it.

Answer (score 0):

just add invoiceitems. those will appear on the client. Invoice now then takes all open invoiceitems and creates an invoice out of it